# lastIndexOf does not work in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
        var currentServerlist = [];
        var newServerIp = document.getElementById('add_server').value; 
        if( CurrentServerIP != newServerIp )
        {
            $('#failoverServers td.row_selector').each(function() {
            var row = $(this).closest('tr');
            var serverIp = row.find('td[rel=ip]').text();
            currentServerlist.push(serverIp);   
            });

            if(currentServerlist.lastIndexOf(newServerIp) != -1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
         }
```

But I find that the lastIndexOf does not work in InternetExplorer (It does in Chrome).

How can I fix this?

Comment: According to W3School, lastIndexOf is supported by IE : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp

Comment: @sdespont, would not be the first time w3schools was wrong

Answer (score 7):

According to the [ES5 compatability table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/), `Array.prototype.lastIndexOf` is supported in all browsers except IE8 and below.

If you need to support such browsers, you can use one of the various [polyfills](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) that are available (or a [more complete ES5 polyfill solution](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)).

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers (IE) don't support a lot of JavaScript properties. I usually find a solution on mdn:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf

The code there:

```
if (!Array.prototype.lastIndexOf)
{
  Array.prototype.lastIndexOf = function(searchElement /*, fromIndex*/)
  {
    "use strict";

    if (this == null)
      throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (len === 0)
      return -1;

    var n = len;
    if (arguments.length > 1)
    {
      n = Number(arguments[1]);
      if (n != n)
        n = 0;
      else if (n != 0 && n != (1 / 0) && n != -(1 / 0))
        n = (n > 0 || -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(n));
    }

    var k = n >= 0
          ? Math.min(n, len - 1)
          : len - Math.abs(n);

    for (; k >= 0; k--)
    {
      if (k in t && t[k] === searchElement)
        return k;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[lastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff679972%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) seems only be implemented in IE9/10. You need to use a shim to support it. See: [ES5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim), line [509-535](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/blob/master/es5-shim.js#L509-L535) in particular.