# Mask email in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new for javascript, i want to mask email id in js

Like **mynewemail@gmail.com** should mask as **m********l@gmail.com**. how do i achieve in js. My below code is not working in ie browser

```
var maskid = "";
var myemailId =  "mynewemail@gmail.com";
var prefix= myemailId.substring(0, myemailId.lastIndexOf("@"));
var postfix= myemailId.substring(myemailId.lastIndexOf("@"));

for(var i=0; i<prefix.length; i++) {
    if(i == 0 || i == prefix.length - 1) {
        maskid = maskid + prefix[i].toString();
    } else {
        maskid = maskid + "*";
    }
}
maskid = maskid + postfix;
```

I want to handle in JS is the requirement.

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't do that in JS as sneaky user could get the initial value (that is the full email). I'd suggest parsing server-side and giving back the "masked" string to the page.

Comment: I want to handle in JS is the requirement.

Comment: Bad requirement. :D You can check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747739/lastindexof-does-not-work-in-internet-explorer) for why it doesn' t work

Answer (score 36):

You can use a regular expression based replacement:

```
var maskid = myemailId.replace(/^(.)(.*)(.@.*)$/,
     (_, a, b, c) => a + b.replace(/./g, '*') + c
);
```

Be careful:

- to do it server side, as any client side replacement could be overturned by the user.
- that not all email adresses are matching your requirement
- that when it matches, it could also not be hiding much

Comment: Most effective and succinct solution.  Only other suggestion I have is to replace `b.replace(/./g, '*')` with a pre-determined number of asterisks - so anybody hacking into the system for specific usernames won't have a clue about the length of the identifier (text before the '@' sign) in the email address.  For instance, both alpha123@gmail.com and alphabetagamma123@gmail.com would appear as a*****3@gmail.com (with 5 asterisks) without giving away the length of the identifier.  Downside - user with 2 similar email addresses of varying length won't know which one you're referring to.

Answer (score 4):

```js
let str = "tonkjhuhuhuy@gmail.com"
str = str.split('');
let finalArr=[];
let len = str.indexOf('@');
str.forEach((item,pos)=>{
(pos>=1 && pos<=len-2) ? finalArr.push('*') : finalArr.push(str[pos]);
})
console.log(finalArr.join(''))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
var maskid = "";
var myemailId =  "mynewemail@gmail.com";
var prefix= myemailId.substring(0, myemailId .lastIndexOf("@"));
var postfix= myemailId.substring(myemailId .lastIndexOf("@"));

for(var i=0; i<prefix.length; i++){
    if(i == 0 || i == prefix.length - 1) {   ////////
        maskid = maskid + prefix[i].toString();
    }
    else {
        maskid = maskid + "*";
    }
}
maskid =maskid +postfix;

console.log(maskid)
```

Comment: But this is not showing the last character of the prefix. Check the question again.

Comment: Hi maioman, if you ask me to remove the check on the first character then how do i get the actual first character without masking?

Comment: Hi @SenthilRS, I edited the answer; let me know if that fixes issue in IE (can't test it at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing it.

```js
var maskedid = "";
var myemailId = "mynewemail@gmail.com";
var index = myemailId.lastIndexOf("@");
var prefix = myemailId.substring(0, index);
var postfix = myemailId.substring(index);

var mask = prefix.split('').map(function(o, i) {
  if (i == 0 || i == (index - 1)) {
    return o;
  } else {
    return '*';
  }
}).join('');

maskedid = mask + postfix;

console.log(maskedid);
```

Comment: Hi Pugazh, .map(function(o, i) is not supported in IE browser and i get error as well(map undefined), i want in plain javascript and not use any jquery plugins

Comment: @SenthilRS : `.map` is not supported in IE versions 8 and below. Can you post the version of IE and the exact error what you get with **your code** (JS in the question) ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
  function getMsakedEmail(email){
    let skipFirstChars = 3;
    let firstThreeChar = email.slice(0, skipFirstChars);

    let domainIndexStart = email.lastIndexOf("@");
    let maskedEmail = email.slice(skipFirstChars, domainIndexStart)
    maskedEmail = maskedEmail.replace(/./g, '*')
    let domain = email.slice(domainIndexStart, email.length);

    return firstThreeChar.concat(maskedEmail).concat(domain);
  }

  function getMsakedEmail2(email){
    let skipFirstChars = 3;
    let firstThreeChar = email.slice(0, skipFirstChars);

    let domainIndexStart = email.lastIndexOf("@");
    let maskedEmail = email.slice(skipFirstChars, domainIndexStart-1)
    maskedEmail = maskedEmail.replace(/./g, '*')
    let domainPlusPreviousChar = email.slice(domainIndexStart-1, email.length);

    return firstThreeChar.concat(maskedEmail).concat(domainPlusPreviousChar);
  }

  let email = "abcdefgh@gmail.com";
  console.log(getMsakedEmail(email));
  console.log(getMsakedEmail2(email));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
endString = input.substring(input.indexOf("@"),input.length);
                            startString = input.substring(0, input.indexOf("@"));
                            output = startString.length > 2 ? startString.substring(0,1) + Array(startString.length-1).join("*") + startString.substring(startString.length-1,startString.length) + endString : startString + endString;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).